# Cannot start activator server

Tags: typesafe-activator

Downloaded and installed activator without a problem.  When I run it (activator.bat), I get this below.  Suggestions?  Thanks!  Tom

```
C:\Program Files\Typesafe Activator\activator-1.0.7>activator ui
Found previous process id: 5068
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:////C:/Program%20Files/Typesafe%20Activator/
activator-1.0.7//repository
Play server process ID is 1236
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/tom/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/com.types
afe.activator/activator-ui/1.0.7/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/Stat
icLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/tom/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.2/com.types
afe.activator/activator-ui/1.0.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticL
oggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorSta
ticBinder]
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
Oops, cannot start the server.
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to create a selector.
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.openSelector(A
bstractNioSelector.java:337)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall that blocks servers?  IIRC - Windows 7 started this thing where the baseline security prevents anything from binding ports until approved.  If you're in a more restricted setting, the pop-up to allow binding doesn't even show.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm running on Windows 7 64-bit.  I'm using Avast anti-virus which manages the Windows Firewall.  I opened up the Java application in Avast to allow all connections on all ports.  Still get the same error.